# Block Controls not showing

Tags: block-editor

I'm building my first Gutenberg block and the problem that I have is that the block control toolbar doesn't show.
I've spend hours comparing my code with other Gutenberg blocks, but couldn't find what is wrong in my code.
I would highly appreciate if someone could look at my code and advice.

Here is my code:

```js
import { registerBlockType } from '@wordpress/blocks';
import { 
    RichText,
    InspectorControls,
    ColorPalette,
    MediaUpload
        } from '@wordpress/block-editor';
import { 
    PanelBody,
    IconButton } from '@wordpress/components';
 
registerBlockType( 'luxworx-blocks/author-block', {
    apiVersion: 2,
    title: 'Luxworx: Author Block',
    icon: 'universal-access-alt',
    category: 'design',
    example: {},
    attributes: {
        title: {
            type: 'string',
            source: 'html',
            selector: 'h2'
        },
        body: {
            type: 'string',
            source: 'html',
            selector: 'p'
        },
        textColor: {
            type: 'string',
            default: 'black'
        },
        bgColor: {
            type: 'string',
            default: 'white'
        },
        authorImage: {
            type: 'string',
            default: null
        }
    },

    edit( {attributes, setAttributes}) {

        // Custom functions
        function updateTitle (newTitle) {
            setAttributes( { title: newTitle}) 
        }
        function updateBody (newBody) {
            setAttributes( { body: newBody}) 
        }
        function onTextColorChange (newColor) {
            setAttributes( {textColor: newColor})
        }
        function onBgColorChange (newColor2) {
            setAttributes( {bgColor: newColor2})
        }
        function onSelectImage(newImage) {
            setAttributes( {authorImage: newImage.sizes.full.url })
        }
 
        return (
            <InspectorControls key="lx-authors-block-setting" style={ { marginBottom:'40px'} }>
                <PanelBody title={ 'Color setting' }>
                    <p><strong>Select text color:</strong></p>
                    <ColorPalette value={ attributes.textColor }
                                    onChange={ onTextColorChange } />
                    <p><strong>Select block bacground color:</strong></p>
                    <ColorPalette value={ attributes.bgColor }
                                    onChange={ onBgColorChange } />
                </PanelBody>
                <PanelBody title={ 'Author image'}>
                    <p><strong>Select author image:</strong></p>
                    <MediaUpload
                        onSelect={ onSelectImage }
                        type="image"
                        value={ attributes.authorImage }
                        render={ ( { open } ) => (
                            <IconButton
                                onClick={ open }
                                icon="upload"
                                className="editor-media-placeholder__button button is-default">
                                Author Image
                            </IconButton>
                        ) } />
                        
                </PanelBody>
            </InspectorControls>,
            <div className="lx-authors-block wp-block" key="container" style={{ backgroundColor: attributes.bgColor}}>
                <img src={ attributes.authorImage} className="lx-authors-image" />
                <div className="lx-author-info">
                    <RichText   
                                placeholder="Authors name"
                                tagName="h2"
                                value={attributes.title}
                                onChange={updateTitle}
                                style={ {color: attributes.textColor }} />
                    
                    <RichText  
                                placeholder="Authors bio"
                                tagName="p"
                                value={attributes.body}
                                onChange={updateBody}
                                style={ {color:attributes.textColor}} />
                </div>
            </div> 
        );
    },
    save( {attributes}) {
        
        return (
            <div className="lx-authors-block wp-block" style={{ backgroundColor: attributes.bgColor }}>
                <img src={ attributes.authorImage} className="lx-authors-image" />
                <div className="lx-author-info">
                    <h2 style={ { color: attributes.textColor }}>{attributes.title}</h2>
                    <RichText.Content tagName="p"
                                    value={attributes.body}
                                    style={ {color:attributes.textColor}}
                                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    },
} );
```

Comment: You should not manually use `wp-block` that's an editor class that the editor is responsible for, _not you_. Use the `useBlockProps` etc hooks or remove those editor based classes to avoid a set of problems you're unaware of.

Answer (score 3):

Your `edit` function is just missing a `[` and `]`, i.e. you forgot to actually return an *array*, like so:

```js
return ([ // add that [
    <InspectorControls key="lx-authors-block-setting" style={ { marginBottom:'40px'} }>
        ...
    </InspectorControls>,
    <div className="lx-authors-block wp-block" key="container" style={{ backgroundColor: attributes.bgColor}}>
        ...
    </div>
]); // and add that ]
```

Or you could instead wrap the elements in a fragment (`<>` and `</>`) or `div` if you want:

```js
return (
    <>
        <InspectorControls key="lx-authors-block-setting" style={ { marginBottom:'40px'} }>
            ...
        </InspectorControls>
        <div className="lx-authors-block wp-block" key="container" style={{ backgroundColor: attributes.bgColor}}>
            ...
        </div>
    </>
);
```

### Update

In response to your answer, and as said by [@TomJNowell](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/736/tom-j-nowell), it's true that you should not manually add the `wp-block` class to your `div` (but I didn't notice you added it there, hence I didn't mention it in my original answer) and instead, because your block type is using the [block API version 2](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/11/18/block-api-version-2/) (note the `apiVersion: 2,` in your code), you should use `useBlockProps` to ensure the block wrapper is recognized properly and added with the proper classes like the `wp-block`.

However, the block editor handbook [stated](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-edit-save/#block-wrapper-props) that:

> If the element wrapper needs any extra custom HTML attributes, these
> need to be passed as an argument to the `useBlockProps` hook.

Therefore, instead of doing `{ ...useBlockProps() } className="lx-authors-block"`:

```js
<div { ...useBlockProps() } className="lx-authors-block" key="editable" style={{ backgroundColor: attributes.bgColor}}>
```

You should actually pass the `className` as an argument to the `useBlockProps` hook:

```js
<div { ...useBlockProps( {
    className: 'lx-authors-block',
    key: 'editable',
    style: { backgroundColor: attributes.bgColor },
} ) }>
```

Otherwise, the `div` will not actually going to have the `wp-block` class and among other issues, the `div` will appear full-width in the editor:

[image: Preview image]

So make sure that you use the correct syntax and your `return` code should look like so:

```js
return ([
    <InspectorControls key="lx-authors-block-setting" style={ { marginBottom:'40px'} }>
        ...
    </InspectorControls>,
    <div { ...useBlockProps( {
        className: 'lx-authors-block',
        key: 'editable',
        style: { backgroundColor: attributes.bgColor },
    } ) }>
        ...
    </div>
]);
```

Which then would give you the correct outcome like so (note the block width and it's also focusable, e.g. when you click on the white background at the top-right corner):

[image: Preview image]

Answer (score 0):

I have found a problem.
My div wrapper was missing { ...useBlockProps() }
So it should be:

```
 <div { ...useBlockProps() } className="lx-authors-block" key="editable" style={{ backgroundColor: attributes.bgColor}}>
```

...

Comment: I've just revised my answer. I hope it helps you more.